# Multiple TableViewCell with Single pickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have multiple `tableViewCell` with single `pickerview`, when open any `pickerView`, PickerView dataSource method call total tableViewCell count.
Plese review my code below.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : SingleLineText = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SingleLineText", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SingleLineText
    pickerView.delegate = self
    cell.pickerViewFields.inputView = pickerView
    return cell
}
```

**PickerView Methods**
This methods call multiple times

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    print(dropDwonArray.count)
    return dropDwonArray.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    print(dropDwonArray[row])
    return dropDwonArray[row]
}
```

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: CellForRowatIndexPath called for every row in uitableviewcell and also when you scroll. so every time cell reuses picker view method also called.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment section what i got is, You do not want to call pickerview's delegates multiple time (reuse) right ?

You can put this condition.

```
  if cell.pickerViewFields.inputView == nil{
                cell.pickerViewFields.inputView = pickerView
            }
```